# How to show min and max values at the end of the axes

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I generate plots like below:

```
from   pylab              import *
import numpy              as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

rcParams['axes.linewidth']   = 2 # set the value    globally
rcParams['font.size']        = 16# set the value globally
rcParams['font.family']      = ['DejaVu Sans']
rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'
rcParams['legend.fontsize']  = 24
rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']  = cycler(color=['grey','b','g','r','orange']) 
rc('lines', linewidth=2, linestyle='-',marker='o')
rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0

t = arange(0,21,1) 
v = 2.0
s = v*t

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.plot(t,s,label='$s=%1.1f\cdot t$'%v)
plt.title('Wykres drogi w czasie $s=v\cdot t$')
plt.xlabel('Czas $t$, s')
plt.ylabel('Droga $s$, m')

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)
legend(loc='best')
plt.xlim(min(t),max(t))
plt.ylim(min(s),max(s))
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image: Generated picture]

When I am changing the value t = arange(0,21,1) for example to t = arange(0,20,1) which gives me for example on the x axis max value= 19.0 my max value dispirs from the x axis. The same situation is of course with y axis.

[image: Wrong picture]

My question is how to force matplotlib to produce always plots where on the axes are max values just **at the end of the axes** like should be always for my purposes or should be possible to chose like an option?

[Imiage from my program in Fortan I did some years ago](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzC4NXZTJ8YPtbjpf6lo7daJ9t9BsDd6/view?usp=sharing)

Matplotlib is more efficiens that I use it but there should be an opition like that (the picture above).

In this way I can always observe max min in text windows or do take addiional steps to make sure about max min values. I would like to read them from axes and the question is ...Are there such possibilites in mathplotlib ??? If not I will close the post.

[Axes I am thinking about more or less](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LaKy9i5z9uXISM0bKu8o3VnmktvvVvE_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why do you write *"like should be always"*? Do you know of any software that does this by default?  So, if your x-axis ends with `19.12345`, you want to have a tick at that position with a completely different format as the rest? And possibly overlapping with them?

Comment: "like should be always...for me" because I have that needs. When I calculate something I want to obserw max values on the plots, It make me sure that I read, calculate something in proper way because for example I know what I can suspect for. I did that kind of plot in Fortran. I took  max - min / number of tiks and it is no problem prepare that kind of axis. Python with matplotlib is more efficient and it is why I use it but it should be that kind of possibilty. Matplotlib is so expanded that it should be one of many possibilites to chose but I think that authors matplotlib forgot about it.

Comment: With matplotlib you can explicitly set ticks, e.g. `plt.xticks([0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,19])` or use some [ticker function](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html). You can write your own ticker function if needed. Including the endpoints is usually unwanted, because of the default padding around most types of plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to solve the problem.

### Set the axes automatic limit mode to round numbers

In the `rcParams` you can do this with

```py
rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
```

And turn off the manual axes limits with min and max

```py
plt.xlim(min(t),max(t))
plt.ylim(min(s),max(s))
```

This will produce the image below. Still, the extreme values of the axes are shown at the nearest "round numbers", but the user can approximately catch the data range limits. If you need the exact value to be displayed, you can see the second solution which cannot be directly used from the `rcParams`.

[image: ticking with auto limits to round numbers]

### or – Manually generate axes ticks

This solution implies explicitly asking for a given number of ticks. I guess there is a way to automatize it depending on the axes size etc. But if you are dealing with more or less every time the same graph size, you can decide a fixed number of ticks manually. This can be done with

```py
plt.xlim(min(t),max(t))
plt.ylim(min(s),max(s))
plt.xticks(np.linspace(t.min(), t.max(), 7))  # arbitrary chosen
plt.yticks(np.linspace(s.min(), s.max(), 5))  # arbitrary chosen
```

generated the image below, quite similar to your image example.

[image: ticking manually]

Comment: Yes thank you very much. The second solution is that I have been looking for. It is enought for me. Thanks a lot.